# how do I assign a function?

Tags: python, tkinter, shutil

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to work with “tkinter”.

The bottom line is that I need to assign a folder deletion function to the button

my code looks like this

```
from tkinter.ttk import LabeledScale 

import shutil

import pathlib 

master = tk.Tk()

lable = tk.Label(text ="delete this?")

lable.pack()

path = "C:\\Users\\kolba\\Desktop\\pythonpool"

def buttonClick():
    shutil.rmtree(path)

button = tk.Button(master, text ="yes!!!", ) #what to put after the comma?
 
button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

how do I make the button work?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [command](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm)

> Function or method to be called when the button is clicked.

In this case

```
def buttonClick():
    shutil.rmtree(path)

button = tk.Button(master, text="yes!!!", command=buttonClick)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the function after the comma:

```
button = tk.Button(master, text ="yes!!!", command = buttonClick)
```

You can read more about **tk.Button** [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm)

Answer (score 0):

you could add a font and you should put a command otherwise that button will be for nothing. something like this:

```
from tkinter.ttk import LabeledScale 

import shutil

import pathlib 

master = tk.Tk()

lable = tk.Label(text ="delete this?")

lable.pack()

path = "C:\\Users\\kolba\\Desktop\\pythonpool"

def buttonClick():
    shutil.rmtree(path)

button = tk.Button(master, text ="yes!!!",command=buttonClick ) 
 
button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```